# git keep staged package.json and npm-shrinkwrap.json but there are no actual content changes

Tags: git, npm

Our build process required to run the following script. The npm install is just to keep the dependency on different machine updated.

```
call npm install --production --no-optional --loglevel verbose
call npm run tsc
call npm run build:main
```

Every time we run the build script, the two files will be listed on the staged changes with no actual content change. As you can see in the following. There are no lines added and also no lines removed but the status changed to Modified.

[image: Tortoise]

When I do the diff, it displayed the message "The text is identical, but the files do not match! The following differences were found: Newlines."

[image: Diff]

I have no idea how to fix it and why it was happening. It is really annoying for my team because every time we have to undo those files before checking in. Any suggestion?

Comment: Check line endings, by default git tries to be smart and auto converts line endings depending on the platform it is being checked out on.

Comment: Thank you. All of our machines are running Window 10. What we saw on the screen the diff screen is there are no different at all. Tried applying as describe here didn't help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653922/git-ignore-line-endings

Comment: npm force lf line endings even on windows : https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17161