# How to force consistent line endings in Git commits with cross-platform compatibility

Tags: windows, git, merge, git-merge, line-endings

I am having issues with merge conflicts due to line endings while working with someone who uses a different OS. I work on Windows and my colleague is on Mac. When he pushes his changes, sometimes files he hasn't worked on show up in the diff as being changed, because the line endings now show `^M` on each file. This has lead to merge conflicts. I read in the Git docs the following:

> Git can handle this by auto-converting CRLF line endings into LF when
>   you add a file to the index, and vice versa when it checks out code
>   onto your filesystem. You can turn on this functionality with the
>   core.autocrlf setting. If you’re on a Windows machine, set it to
>   true — this converts LF endings into CRLF when you check out code:
>
> $ git config --global core.autocrlf true If you’re on a Linux or macOS
>   system that uses LF line endings, then you don’t want Git to
>   automatically convert them when you check out files; however, if a
>   file with CRLF endings accidentally gets introduced, then you may want
>   Git to fix it. You can tell Git to convert CRLF to LF on commit but
>   not the other way around by setting core.autocrlf to input:
>
> $ git config --global core.autocrlf input This setup should leave you
>   with CRLF endings in Windows checkouts, but LF endings on macOS and
>   Linux systems and in the repository.

This makes sense, but I am still unclear on how the files are actually committed in the repo. For example, if he creates a file on his system, it will have all `LF` line endings, correct? So when he commits, I presume those line endings are retained as-is. When I pull, my `autocrlf` being `true` will check them out with `CRLF` line endings, as far as I understand. (I get the warnings `warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in <file x>; The file will have its original line endings in your working directory`)

A couple questions about this: when the warning says "working directory", what is that referring to? Also, when I then make changes, or create other files, all of which have the `CRLF` line endings and commit+push, are they stored in the repo as `CRLF` or `LF`?

I imagine the ideal is to have the repo strip anything but `LF` everytime a commit is made; is this what happens? What's going on under the hood and how can we force this to behave consistently?

Comment: `A couple questions about this: when the warning says "working directory", what is that referring to?` "working directory" refers to the files on your harddrive that you are currently editing.

Comment: Use a `.gitattributes` file to defined the expected eol of files (which is the only one good practice). See https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings#per-repository-settings

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Q1 Enforcing consistent lineendings
>
> Q2 Enforcing at commit as well as checkout (comment)

I'll divide this into 2 parts: Practice and Principle

## Practice

Expansion of  [code-apprentice's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57961890/3700414) suggestion

1. Strictly avoid `autocrlf` — See why [autocrlf is always wrong](https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/advent_day_1_gitattributes_for_text_files.html).
   And [here](https://git.vger.kernel.narkive.com/Hypnrw9x/core-autocrlf-considered-half-assed) for the core git devs arguing about the ill-thoughtout-ness of autocrlf. Note particularly that the implementer is annoyed at the *critic* but doesn't deny the *criticism*.
2. Religiously use `.gitattributes` instead
3. Use `safecrlf=true` to enforce commit-cleanliness.  `safecrlf` is the answer to your Q2 – a file that would change on check-in check-out round tripping would error out on the check-in stage itself.

When a new repo is init-ed:
Go through `ls -lR` and choose for it's type `text, binary` or ignore (ie put it in .gitignore)

Debugging:
Use [git-check-attr](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr) to check that attribute matching and computation are as desired

## Principle

### Data Store

We may treat git as a data-store loosely analogous to how a USB drive is one.

We say the drive is working if the stuff we put in comes out *the same*. Else it's corrupted. Likewise if the file we commit comes out *the same* on checkout the repo is fine else (something) is borked. The key question is

## What does "same" mean?

It's non-trivial because we implicitly apply different standards of "sameness" in different contexts!

### Binary Files

- A binary file is a sequence of bytes
- Preserving that sequence faithfully amounts to reproducing the file

### Text Files

...are different

- A text file consists of a sequence of «printable characters» — let's leave the printable char notion unspecified other than to say **no cr no lf!**
- How these lines are separated (or terminated) is **again unspecified**
- Symbolically:
  type Line = [Char]
  type File = [Line]
- Expanding on the 1st unspecified gives us ASCII, Latins, Unicode etc etc... Not relevant to this question
- Expanding on the 2nd is what distinguishes windows *nix etc. JFTR [this kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_set_(IBM_mainframe)) of file may be little known by the younger generation but also exists. And is particularly useful to remember that the notion "sequence of lines" can be imposed at many different levels.

  **We don't care how the sameness respects the unspecified parts**

To return to our

## USB drive analogy

When I copy foo.txt from Windows to Linux I expect the *contents* to be invariant. However I'm quite satisfied if `H:foo.txt` **changes to** `/media/name/Transcend/foo.txt`. In fact it would be more than a bit annoying if the windowsisms came through untranslated or vice versa.

Far-fetched??  [¡¡Think again!!](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?289178-A-file-called-C-nppdf32Log-debuglog-txt-in-my-root-directory)

IOW thanks to splendid folks like Theodore T'so we take it for granted that Linux can read a windows file (system). This happens because a non-trivial amt of

- abstraction matching
- abstraction hiding

happens under the hood.

## Back to Git

We therefore expect that a file checked in to git is *the same* that's checked out... at a different time... And OS!

The catch is that the notion of same is sufficiently non-trivial that git needs some help from us in achieving that "sameness" to our satisfaction... That help is called `.gitattributes`!

Comment: Core git devs discussion link: https://git.vger.kernel.narkive.com/Hypnrw9x/core-autocrlf-considered-half-assed - the one you have is broken. I'd also say that the implementer points out critic's attitude and attempts at shaming and agrees only "that if a similar situation happened by mistake and your project does want to enforce core.autocrlf, it would be nicer if there is an easy-to-use one-time clean-up procedure." and that having index keep the CRLF/LF data would be better (far cry from the aggressive criticism). Still a very nice answer.

Comment: @LAFKsaysReinstateMonica Link changed — Tnx! A more philosophic version [here](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/how-do-i-teach-git-to-a-teenager/6160#6160). [Find out now that that new SO link there has died!]

Answer (score 16):

`autocrlf` is widely considered to be broken. The modern way to handle line endings is with [`.gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). GitHub has a great tutorial about how to use it [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings#per-repository-settings).

Comment: That sounds wise; thank you for the insight there. From what I can tell, this instructs git to change the line endings to whatever I specify when I check them out into my working directory. Does it also specify changing line endings to something consistent when they are committed?

Comment: This answer deserves expansion (because the opposite - use autocrlf - is so prevalent. Pls check mine below.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE LINK TO THE TUTORIAL! IT SAVED MY LIFE. the problem for me was binary `.whl` files getting changed when pushing to repository. I could prevent this by adding `*.whl binary` into the `.gitattributes` file.

Comment: I guess you are suggesting to avoid global `git config core.autocrlf` and use a per-repository `.gitattributes` file. But it is not clear whether you are also advising against any "auto" line ending modes. For example, could you please clarify whether writing `* text=auto` in the `.gitattributes` is acceptable or is that also broken?

Comment: @RossBencina I am simply emphasizing that we should now use `.gitattributes` rather than `git config core.autocrlf`. I'm not making any comment about what settings to use specifically.