# How to git commit some files with CRLF and others with LF on Mac?

Tags: git, github, newline, core.autocrlf

I have a repo that contains 7 files with `CRLF` and everything else with `LF`. I'm working on a mac which, by default, uses `LF`.

When I commit my changes on `git` and push it to Github, and my colleague pulls the branch, those 7 files show up as `LF`.

What I want to do is to be able to commit everything as is on my mac (i.e. 7 files with `CRLF` and everything else with `LF`) and also make sure when someone pulls my branch on a mac or linux they get exactly same thing as I committed? Bear in mind I've already committed these 7 files with `LF` (accidentally) as I didn't know how git is changing these things. So, I need to make sure changes get to the remote branch as well.

I read a handful of QAs, but mostly got confused between `core.autocrlf` and `.gitattributes`. Any help and/or explanation of how to achieve this is much appreciated.

Comment: Forget about `core.autocrlf`, use only `.gitattributes`.

Comment: @phd suggestion [expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644154/3700414)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be kind of careful here, because Git has some built in conversions, and they *strongly favor LF-only line endings*.  If you use the built-in conversions, that's what you'll actually get in your *repository*.  But we must distinguish between what's in the *repository* and what's in your *work-tree*.

You do not work with files in the repository, because they're unsuitable for doing work.  You work with files in your work-tree.  And, in one sense, Git doesn't even store *files*, because the basic unit of Git storage is the *commit*.  But commits themselves do store (snapshots of) files, so in that sense, Git stores files.  It's just that they're all-the-commit, or none-of-it, at a time.

The files inside each Git commit are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed form.  The other programs on your computer, including your editors and file-viewers, cannot work with these files.<sup>1</sup>  They're great for archival and completely useless, at least on their own, for getting any *new* work done.

So, when you use `git checkout` to pick a particular commit, Git *extracts* these files.  They come out of the commit, going from the special, read-only, Git-only, freeze-dried format, to plain ordinary files.  These uncompressed and rehydrated files can be used by *every* program on your computer.  Those are the files you will see and work with, and Git copies them into your *work-tree:* the area in which you do your work.

The work-tree is not really part of the repository.  And, when Git does file-format changes according to `.gitattributes` or `core.autocrlf` or any of these other options you can choose, Git *only* does them when copying files from the index to the work-tree, and when copying files from the work-tree to the index.  We haven't touched on the index yet, but it's time to do that.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some editors probably *can*, at this point: I'd be surprised if there is no GNU-emacs mode for viewing Git internal objects, for instance. :-)  But most in general can't, and don't need to anyway.

---

#### The index sits *between* the commits and the work-tree

The index is perhaps best described, in one phrase, as *the place where you build your next commit*.  This thing—which Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*—actually has multiple functions.  In particular it's quite crucial when dealing with a conflicted merge.  But for our purposes here, we only care about the fact that it sits between the committed files, and the work-tree copies of those files.<sup>2</sup>

That is: when you ask Git to check out a particular commit, what Git does is to *copy*<sup>3</sup> the files that are stored in that commit into the index.  Unlike the frozen files in commits, though, the copies in the index *can* be overwritten.  Then, having copied the commit to the index, Git now copies the index's files to the work-tree.

This last step—copy index file to work-tree—is when Git does end-of-line conversions.  **There is only one conversion Git can do here** on its own: it can turn newline terminated lines into CRLF terminated lines.

Now that all your files are in your work-tree, you can work on them as much as you like.  You can keep the line endings the same, or change them as you like.  You can replace files wholesale or edit them with editors or whatever you want.  They're just *files* and they are totally under your control.

Now that you've *changed* these files, though, you might want your *next* commit to have the updated files.  Here, you must run `git add`: what `git add` does is to copy the work-tree file into the index.  This compresses and otherwise Git-ifies the file, so that it's now in the freeze-dried *format* in the index, ready to be committed.<sup>4</sup>  And, once again, **there is only one conversion built into Git here:** it can replace CRLF line endings with newline-only line endings.

#### Git cannot change *to* CRLF endings *in the repository*

Take note of the two transformations that are built into Git.  *All* of the control settings, whether in `.gitattributes` or not, are just turning these conversion settings on or off.  Either Git turns newlines into CRLF on the way out—from index to work-tree—or it doesn't.  Either Git turns CRLF into newlines on the way in, from work-tree to index, or it doesn't.  There is no process by which Git can turn newline-endings to CRLF-endings in the index.

You can, of course, simply *not use* the transformations that are built in to Git.  But if you want to *work with* CRLF endings, yet *store*—in the repository—newline-only endings, you *can* arrange for that to occur.  The real questions here are:

- Do you care what's in the *repository*, inside commits, or only what's in the *work-tree*?
- If you care about what's in the repository, what do you want in the *repository*, inside the commits?
- If Git's favored newline-only endings are acceptable in the repository, as long as you get CRLF endings in the work-tree, are you willing to pay the slight cost of doing these conversions?

If the answer to the last question is that they are acceptable and yes, then forget about what's in the *repository* and concentrate on getting the right setting in `.gitattributes`.  Git will do the called-for transformations during file extraction operations and `git add` operations.

If the answer to the second question is that you care about what's in the *repository*, and you want CRLF endings, you probably shouldn't use Git's built in conversions.  You can write your own *smudge* and *clean* filters to do what you want: make your "clean" filter store lines with CRLF endings.  (The fact that there are no built in methods to do this means that if you think you want that, you should be pretty sure: the Git folks do try to cover Windows and MacOS reasonably well.)

---

<sup>2</sup>In a sense, the index isn't *required*.  Other version control systems function just fine without one.  But here, we must know about it, because it's how all this stuff actually works, in Git.

<sup>3</sup>Git doesn't actually copy them.  Because of their dehydrated / freeze-dried form, Git can just *refer to* the committed files.  What's in the index is really Git internal *blob object* hash IDs, plus each file's name, plus a lot of make-it-go-fast *cache* data, all arranged in a way that is suitable for Git, and not suitable for anything else.  But unless you start looking at the parts of the index, e.g., with `git ls-files --stage` or `git update-index`, none of this really matters.  You can think of what's in the index as copies of files, and it all works out.

<sup>4</sup>Technically, `git add` makes a new *blob* object, or re-uses some existing blob object if there is one with the right content.  Then it puts the blob hash into the index, as noted in footnote 3.  But again you can just think of this as a copy operation: it works out the same.

Comment: Folks who are annoyed and wondering why git isn't using their `.gitattributes` file (like I was) should heed this post and take note of this comment. It is possible that the file *in the repo* (not the work tree as described here) has CRLF endings and `git diff` shows them being removed because it is removing them *in the repo*. `git cat-file -p some-branch:file.txt | xxd` to see the *real line endings in the repo*. If you see `0d0a` then the *repo* has CRLF endings. Check your *work tree* file before and after committing the "change" and you'll notice it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that CRLF line end is important and shouldn't be converted it would be safest to use `.gitattributes` file which will override local git settings.

You can create `.gitattributes` file as explained in the [Github docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings#per-repository-settings). For example if your CRLF files share a common suffix:

```
# Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
*.sln text eol=crlf
```