# How can I use `LF` line endings in Git for Windows in 2020 for good?

Tags: git, line-endings, editorconfig, git-for-windows

Our repository uses `LF`, my Git for Windows installation uses **Checkout as-is, commit Unix-style line endings**,

[image]

but I still end up with wall of errors in every file I checkout in my IDE as it still receives `CRLF` all the time even though it does support `LF` and is configured to use `LF` via checked in `.editorconfig` file (or in its own settings).:

`.editorconfig`

```
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = lf
```

---

> It is 2020 already and IDEs and tooling already support `LF` on Windows, so how can I have the nice things too?

Comment: Pls see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644154/3700414). With a 4th point added in your case : core.eol=lf. Try with a fresh repo before trying to clean messed repos. Important to emphasize: autocrlf should be false at all levels: system, global, repo

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two git config attributes that affect the line endings: **`core.autocrlf`** and **`core.eol`**.
Previously, you were told to use `core.autocrlf = true` to be able to work on cross-platform projects, but it's not `true` any more.

If your system/IDE/tooling support `LF` and you **do want** to use `LF` as everyone else in your team without any silent `lf->crlf->lf` normalizations, you must turn off `autocrlf` and configure `eol` to not infer `native` line endings, but force it to use `lf`.

#### Now there are two ways to achieve `LF` in all your files a/o repos:

1. Globally for all repositories on your local machine.
2. Per-repository via checked-in `.gitattributes` file.
   *This file overrides any local configuration for everyone who clones the repo.*

*I personally recommend to go with both for all local repos and to ensure cross-platform cross-dev consistency.*

---

### 1) Globally for all repositories on your local machine

Being in your working directory (your local repo):

1. First commit everything
2. Let's be paranoid a bit and set it both globally and in repo as well. Just in case.

   ```
   git config --global core.eol lf
   git config --global core.autocrlf false

   git config core.eol lf
   git config core.autocrlf false
   ```
3. Delete everything "code" except `.git`.
   You can also omit dependencies, installed files (such as `node_modules`), build files and any *git-ignored* file as well.
4. and lastly run

   ```
   git reset --hard HEAD
   ```

Things should be working now. Newly checked files should follow the new configuration and keep whatever line-endings were cloned from the remote repo.

Note that if your remote repo uses mix of `crlf` `lf` endings, you will also have to run and push

```
git add --renormalize .
```

---

### 2) Per-repository via checked-in `.gitattributes` file

Being in your working directory (your local repo):

1. Create `.gitattributes` file in the root with this content:

   ```
   * text=auto eol=lf
   ```
2. Commit the file (and everything else)
3. Same as above
4. Same as above

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: After you introduce the file into the repository, it is necessary that everyone who still has old CRLF files does step 3 and 4 to update their working directory as just checking out the commit doesn't affect already existing files.

[image: git reset hard]

---

## Notes

setting `core.autocrlf` to `true` or `input` overrides `core.eol`

https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreautocrlf

`core.autocrlf = input` is the preferred value on unix systems.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41282375/985454
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4425433/985454

## Troubleshooting

Reinstall git for windows with third option (as in the screenshot in Q)

> Checkout as is - Commit as is (`core.autocrlf = false`)

Comment: For step 3 you could use something like `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 rm` to only remove git tracked files.

Comment: @Qtax I have no experience with this command in particular, but if it does what you say then definitely.

Answer (score 3):

The way to go is to use a `.gitattributes` with the good instruction to give to git.

See https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/git_for_windows_line_endings.html

For your case, it should be: `* text=auto eol=lf`

`.editorconfig` is only for saving files for editors supporting it...

But after that, you will have to normalize the files:

`git add --renormalize .`

You could find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50645024/717372

Comment: Actually I don't want `CRLF`. And yes, I am talking about IDE and tooling that supports `LF`, hence the `.editorconfig`. From what I have learned, `.gitattributes` can be quite complicated and you need to tweak certain extensions there. Anyway, to use `.gitattributes` you still need to make sure each dev's git installation is set properly and therefore I think the other solution is more straight forward and requires less work and further maintanance.

Comment: I mean, `.gitattributes` file works only if you also set `core.autocrlf = false`. But if you also set `core.eol = lf`, then the `.gitattributes` has implicitly value `* text=auto eol=lf` even if you don't create it IIUC.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit the line to change to `LF` (edited now). And no `.editorconfig` is not the solution. And yes, `.gitattributes` is the good solution nowaday because it doesn't required that all devs have rightfully configured their git. Did you read the post from edward thomson? And no, you're solution is not the one more staright forward because some time to times a dev commit bad eol...

Comment: No, `.gitattributes` overrides `core.autocrlf`, period.  Get it right, check it in to your repository, and it doesn't matter what `core.autocrlf` or `core.eol` are set to.  That's _the point_ of `.gitattributes`.

Comment: As I said in the Question, the repo uses `LF` already, I don't need to run normalization. Can you confirm that for `.gitattributes` to take effect, one must set their local git config to `core.autocrlf = false`?

Comment: No.  `.gitattributes` overrides `core.autocrlf`, it doesn't matter what you have it set to.  If you have a `.gitattributes` configured for a file, `core.autocrlf` will be ignored.

Comment: this is awesome!

Comment: I advise you to do the normalization. If all your files are good, you will have nothing to commit and it will be perfect. And you could also see the bad effects if you did something wrong.

Comment: I have actually just tried your way with a fresh intall of Git for Windows with default `autocrlf=true` and it checked out the files with `CRLF` line endings and `git add --renormalize .` took several seconds but did nothing eventually. Note that I firste cloned the repo, then added `.gitattributes` file. Should it be done differently? Should I first push the file and clone again?

Comment: The solution was to delete everything and do a hard reset. I can imagine a fresh clone would also work.

Comment: That makes sense - you were (hopefully) already normalized since `core.autocrlf` indicates that files are CRLF in the working directory but go into the repository as LF.  In your new setup, you want files as LF in the working directory _and_ the repository.  So there's nothing to renormalize in your repository.  Indeed a fresh checkout is all that's needed to update the on-disk files.