# Git shows the difference between files on merge as whole files whereas both have CRLF on the end of lines

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, newline

I'm trying to fix merge conflict and see Git (in Visual Code) shows the whole file instead of just one line. I googled and found the problem may be with line endings.
I found one of the team added the .gitattributes file with the following content:

```
* -crlf
```

Can it be the reason an how can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Why it happened? Probably you (one of you) has git setup to change EOL format of files. `autocrlf` comes to mind.

Comment: @eftshift0 can you elaborate more what should I do on my side (Windows) to see the differences normally? I added more information in the post. Thanks

Comment: -crlf means -text. This is of course asking for trouble because you (your team-mate) is saying all files are non text files . Better to keep core.eol to lf if that's what one wants.  More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644154/3700414) Correcting a messed repo however is more work. The recently added renormalize option in git add helps.