# Configuring git to support programmers working with different Operating Systems

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, gitlab

We have some programmers, one working in Linux, one working in Windows, and another in OSX. We need to push to the same git repo but I am afraid that this could create estrange complications. In fact, I once cloned this repo using Linux and I could not find some folders that appeared in the repo which was originally created from windows. Is there any setting in Git (particularly, gitlab) that could help us to have a repo "working" for any of our platforms?

Comment: All of the problems posted here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/os-compatibility?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably start with:

(1) To avoid the annoying OSX `.DS_Store` files being accidentally commited or show as untracked, add `.DS_Store` to the top level `.gitignore` file in your project.

(2) To avoid problems with line endings (eg. Linux vs. Windows), add `* text=auto` to the `.gitattributes` file.

(3) As Windows is not case sensitive, you may want to set the [`core.ignoreCase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.14.6#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase) option to `true` (`git config core.ignoreCase true`).

(4) In Git for Windows, you might stumble upon `Filename too long` problems , setting the option `core.longPaths` to `true` may help in this case (`git config core.longPaths true`).

...

However, each project is different and there no "one fits all" answer.

Comment: but ignoring case could make the source code incompatible for Linux files. I mean, two Linux files named as  Myfile.txt and myfile.txt will destroy each other at the cloning from Windows, isn't it?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga but you can not have Myfile.txt and myfile.txt on a Windows filesystem.

Comment: True, but the OSX or Linux guys could do this and tease the Windows guy.

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga if you want to develop on Windows, you need to tell the Linux and OSX guys that having Myfile.txt and myfile.txt is not allowed or you don't develop on Windows.

Comment: We all are targeting Android.. But I agree we might need to make this rule for us.

Comment: What do you think of the next posting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960566/how-to-force-consistent-line-endings-in-git-commits-with-cross-platform-compatib

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga I would agree, use `.gitattributes` instead of `core.autocrlf `.

Comment: Do not change `core.ignoreCase`.  It's not a configuration option; git detects whether your repository is on a case sensitive filesystem or not at initialization time.  It saves this state in the configuration so that it doesn't have to needlessly requery over and over again, every time you run git.  Changing this to the wrong value will break things.

Comment: @EdwardThomson What if you initialize the repo on Windows and then work on Linux or vice versa? Who decides whether "File.txt" and "file.txt" are different files or not.

Comment: The underlying operating system.  The git configuration - including `core.ignorecase` - is per-repository, not shared.  This means that if you work on different systems with different case rules, you'll need to be disciplined, and unfortunately git itself gives you no simple way to enforce this.  `core.ignorecase` _sounds_ like a thing that would help, unfortunately, it is really not.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Lets say you are disciplined and within the team you agreed on that "File.txt" and "file.txt" is the same file. Would it be make sense to set `core.ignorecase` to `true`?

Comment: No.  It is not a setting, it is a cache of your filesystem’s state.  By changing it, you will break the way git looks at your filesystem.