# Do I have to apply core.autocrlf everytime?

Tags: git

I learned that `git config --global core.autocrlf true` is the method used to solve `LF will be replaced by CRLF` error in git. At first, I thought that this method would be applied continuously once applied, but it seems that is not the case when I actually use it. Whenever I use `git add`, `LF will be replaced by CRLF` warning always comes up.
So my question is:

1. Do I have to apply `core.autocrlf` whenever I needed?
2. Is there any method to apply `git config --global core.autocrlf true` permanently?

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628305/windows-git-warning-lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-is-that-warning-tail-backwar

Comment: Pls see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644154/3700414

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is merely that you said `true` when you should have said `false`. You want to turn this replacement feature *off*.