# Why does setting `* text=auto` cause commits to use crlf line endings?

Tags: git

when setting `* text=auto`, all textfiles automatically seem to be converted to crlf line endings when committing.

What is the setting that causes auto to set the line ending to crlf and how do I change that to lf?

Comment: What test are you doing that makes you think this is happening? I ask because I think the answer is that it doesn't. It should be the other way around- it should convert CRLF to LF for text files, and this happens at *commit* rather than at *push*. However, if a file was already committed with CRLF (by someone who didn't have the text=auto setting on), then it won't be converted. Also, even if it's converted in the commit, it will *not* update your working copy, so make sure your test looks at the committed version instead of your local copy.

Comment: @TTT when I commit, I see a message `"warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in <myfile>.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory"`. This makes me believe that somewhere in my settings, git believes that it should automatically convert LF to CRLF for text files.

Comment: It appears you have a repo whose line endings are already messed. I suggest first you try with a clean repo with [my suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644154/3700414) from the outset.  If the problem goes then we can see how to scrub an existing repo of bad line endings

Comment: @Rusi Some of the line endings changed from crlf to lf. That's the correct way they should be handled.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying... But AFAIK if your gitattributes are set right things should "just work" with no spurious changes/messages. Nevertheless I don't recommend text=auto because it asks git to guess. Better **you** decide which files are text and which binary

Answer (score 1):

As [TTT points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500311/why-does-setting-text-auto-cause-commits-to-use-crlf-line-endings#comment121061843_68500311), the premise of your question is wrong.  Answering it is difficult, like answering the question *why is the sun frozen* or *why is the sky a [brilliant chartreuse](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1448/0376/products/MG_5932_1024x1024.png?v=1591482684) at noon*, for instance.<sup>1</sup>

There are a few key tricks to know, in order to understand how `.gitattributes` conversions work.  We start with one basic fact: *No part of any commit can ever be changed.*  This means that already-committed files *are not affected* by `eol=` settings.  But: files that are being *extracted from* a commit *can* be changed at any time,<sup>2</sup> and files that are being written into Git's database, so that they can be included in a *future* commit, *can* be changed during the act of compressing the file into the special internal Git-only format that Git uses inside commits.<sup>3</sup>

What this means in practice is that `text` file modifications, as controlled by the `eol=` settings, work, in Git, *during* the insertion and extraction of files.  There are, in Git, **only two such built in conversions**:

- Git can change CRLF line endings into LF-only line endings *when adding a file* (to the index / staging area, so as to be committed later).  That is, Git can *remove* CRLFs and *replace them with LF-only* in the *committed* files.
- Git can change LF-only line endings to CRLF line endings *when extracting a file* (from a commit, or from Git's index / the staging area, to your working tree).  That is, Git can make it *seem as if* the stored file has CRLF line endings, even though it does not.

So, when using `text` and `eol=crlf`, the files that *Git is storing* (in your repository, inside commits, in the read-only, compressed, Git-only format) are actually LF-only, *provided that Git did the conversion on those files during a `git add` step*.  However, every time you *look at* those files by extracting them to your working tree, you *see* files that have CRLF line endings, because Git *changed* those LF-only line endings to CRLF endings during the extraction process.

When using `text` and `eol=lf`, the files that *Git is storing* are actually LF-only, and when you look at them, you see LF-only endings.  The same provisos apply of course: Git has to have *applied* these settings at the right conversion points.

The bottom line here is that we can say that **if** *Git itself* has any kind of "text preference", it's for **LF-only line endings**.  Those are what end up being done to the stored, internal-format files, regardless of how you set the `eol=` setting.  The `eol=` setting is not meant for *Git*, though: it is meant for *you*, and/or for your OS.  It affects what Git does during *extraction* of those files.  The `text` setting itself is what affects what Git does during *insertion* of those files' content into the Git repository, and what Git does here is to convert to LF-only.

---

<sup>1</sup>Someone will now no doubt find some historical incident in which the sky turned chartreuse at noon.

<sup>2</sup>This follows from the fact that these are ordinary everyday files on your computer, which can (presumably) be changed.  They can certainly be modified by Git as it does the copying *from* some commit, *to* an ordinary file on your computer, since Git is the thing doing this copying: the files stored inside Git are in a peculiar, compressed, Git-only, and de-duplicated format, that most programs would not be able to read at all, so Git *must* change them during extraction.  While it changes them by decompressing, it can make additional changes as well.

<sup>3</sup>As with the extraction phase, it is the Git software doing this compressing (and eventual de-duplicating) and hence the bytes being stored are completely, totally under Git's control.  Git can thus make any changes it wants—up until the file is *stored*, at which point it becomes completely, totally read-only, due to the hash ID scheme Git uses.<sup>4</sup>

<sup>4</sup>Technically, if one could easily break the cryptographic hash, it *would* be possible to change stored files, within certain limitations.  See, e.g., [this web-site](http://shattered.it/).  The known cases of such files don't actually work for Git because of Git's header prefixes, though, and this is not yet practical even though computing has progressed since 2017.  Git itself is moving to SHA-256 at some point, too.

Comment: If git never replaces LF with CRLF when committing, I really have no idea what to make of "warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in <myfile>. The file will have its original line endings in your working directory" when committing. Could you elaborate on that in your answer?

Comment: The text of the warning is confusing, but it means that the *working tree* copy will have what are *currently* LF-only line endings replaced with CRLF line endings (in a future checkout, but not right now). Note that this is particularly bad behavior in a JPG image, for instance, where those LF-only "line endings" are not actually *line endings* at all, they're just bytes with value 10 decimal.

Comment: That's indeed quite a big problem, not only for images, but also for text files, that will silentently have the correct LF line endings in the working directory replaced by incorrect CRLF line endings. Sounds like a dangerous misfeature that can only lead to misery.